# Memory warrning tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uitableview

I have two tableviewcell in xib file and I use both of them.

When I use one of them the memory is still 7.3MB, but when I use both memory grow very fast.

Please help me. I don't now what is wrong.

My code is below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.events objectAtIndex:row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifierL = @"LeftCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierR = @"RightCell";


    SampleTableCell *cellLeft = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierL];
    SampleTableCell *cellRight = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierR];

    if (cellLeft == nil) {
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LeftTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SampleTableCell class]]) {
                cellLeft = (SampleTableCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (cellRight == nil) {
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RightTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SampleTableCell class]]) {
                cellRight = (SampleTableCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }



    return (row%2==0)?cellRight:cellLeft;
}
```

Comment: did you check your memory crash report or intrument log because your code is looking fine, what is you are doing with cell there is some more you have left i guess

Comment: I see no problem in this piece of code. When does the memory footprint grow? While scrolling the table view?

Comment: Two theories: 1- Are you sure that your `SampleTableCell` has the correct reusableCellIdentifier? (check that in your xib) If not, it means you're creating way too many rows. 2- You should determine which cell you have to create before creating both of them. That only matters for the first cell creations though.

Comment: Have you enabled Zoombies in your code after using 2 cells?

Comment: I only show cell, I didn't make here.
it is in my cell class:
property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelDate;
property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelName;
property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelAdress;


Memory grow when scrolling table

Comment: Loïs Di Qual what means second point?

Comment: HA! Then your problem is with the strong references:  property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelDate;
These IBOutlet's should be weak:  property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelDate;

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to do this. You are creating both cells for every row, but you only use one of them. You should also use the newer way to use a xib based cell -- that is, use registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: in viewDidLoad, to register both nibs. Do your check for odd/even rows first, and dequeue the correct cell (no need to check for nil when using the register method). You do it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SampleCell1" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SampleCell1"];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SampleCell2" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SampleCell2"];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        SampleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SampleCell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // populate cell with data
        return cell;
    }else{
        SampleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SampleCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // populate cell with data
        return cell;
    }
}
```

This is all you need to do. There's no need to check for a nil cell, because dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: is guaranteed to return a valid cell if you either register a nib, or make the cell in a storyboard (in which case you don't need to register anything).

Comment: Have you got any example?
Should I Create in viewDidLoad in my Controller?
And how I can use it in cellForRowAtIndex

Comment: Creating both cells shouldn't be a problem. ARC should release the unused cell immediately when the method returns. Although it's an interesting question whether setting self as the nib's owner counteracts ARC in this case. 
Can you try it without using owner:self in loadNibNamed:?

Comment: @Unmerciful, I've updated my answer to show you how to do this. I created a class, SampleCell, and two xib files, SampleCell1 and SampleCell2 for this example.

Comment: @TamásZahola, yes, what you wrote is true -- I should have been more clear in my explanation. I didn't mean to imply, that making both cells was causing the memory problem. It's just not good code, and so it shouldn't be done that way. I don't know if my answer will fix the problem, but it shows the way that Apple recommends doing a table view with xib based cells now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create only the cell you need. Your code should be like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.events objectAtIndex:row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifierL = @"LeftCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierR = @"RightCell";

    if (cellLeft == nil) {
        SampleTableCell *cellLeft = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierL];
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LeftTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SampleTableCell class]]) {
                cellLeft = (SampleTableCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cellLeft;
    }

    if (cellRight == nil) {
        SampleTableCell *cellRight = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierR];
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RightTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SampleTableCell class]]) {
                cellRight = (SampleTableCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cellRight;
    }



    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change to this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.events objectAtIndex:row];

    SampleTableCell *cell;


    if(row%2==0){

        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RightTableCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];

    }else{
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LeftTableCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.labelName.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

But I don't know that is good idea?